# Is there any polymorphism in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism

Suppose both `base` and `son` class have a method `method_1`,

and there's another method `method_2` of `base`.

inside `base::method_2`,how can I point `$this->method_1` to `base::method_1` no matter whether `$this` is a instance of `base` or `son`?

Comment: What you're talking about isn't polymorphism. Ignoring a sub-class's reimplementation of a method? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @meagar, I agree. If you don't want it to be overridden, it should be `private` or `final`.

Comment: You should edit the title of your question to something like, "Trouble with PHP OOP Hierarchy", or "How to bypass inheritance - PHP OOP"... current is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
<?php

class base {
  public function method1() {
    echo "base:method1\n";
  }
  public function method2() {
    if(get_class($this) == 'base') {
      $this->method1();
    }
    else {
      parent::method1();
    }
    echo "base:method2\n";
  }
}



class son extends base {
  public function method1() {
    echo "son:method1\n";
  }
}


$obj = new son();

$obj->method2();
```

where the call to method2 would always use the base version of the method1.

The best way I could do it is as above, but this code won't work since base has no parent.  I'm pretty sure what you're trying to do isn't possible.

This is the error you will get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want. Props to dbers for the example code (even if his didn't quite work).

```
<?php

class base {
  public function method1() {
    echo "base::method1\n";
  }
  public function method2() {
    if (get_parent_class($this) === FALSE) {
      echo get_class($this)." has no parent\n";
      $this->method1();
    } else {
      echo get_class($this)." has parent\n";
      call_user_func(array(get_parent_class($this), 'method1'));
    }
  }
}

class son extends base {
  public function method1() {
    echo "son::method1\n";
  }
}

$b = new base();
$b->method2();

$s = new son();
$s->method2();

?>
```

Outputs:

```
base has no parent
base::method1
son has parent
base::method1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the function private:

```
<?php
class A
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->foo();
    $this->bar();    
  }

  private function foo() { echo "A::foo()\n"; }
  public function bar() { echo "A::bar()\n"; }
}

class B extends A
{
  public function foo() { echo "B::foo()\n"; }
  public function bar() { echo "B::bar()\n"; }
}

new B();
?>
```

The output is:

```
A::foo()
B::bar()
```

Comment: What is this canon that you speak of, and why do you expect PHP to adhere to it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. It's singular (one parent).

`son->method_1` can add to or override ALL of `base->method_1` functionality.

`son->method_1` can simply add an additional function, and utilize the rest of the functionality of it's parent's instance of `method_1`

So calling `$this->method_1` would use `base->method_1`, and `son->method_1` as long as what you want to use from base isn't overridden in son.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a method that doesn't exist in your subclass, PHP will traverse the class hierarchy until it finds an ancestor class which implements the function you want. This means that if your `son` class doesn't implement `method_2`, PHP will automatically look for the nearest ancestor which does. In your case, it will call `method_2` of `base` as you want.

If you *are* overriding the `method_2` in your `son` class, and you want to do your own implementation of `method_2` *and also call the `base::method_2` implementation* then you can use the `parent` keyword:

```
class son extends base {
  public function method_2() {
    parent::method_2();
    //do son::method_2()-specific stuff here
  }
}
```

You can't chain `parent` calls together, so if `base` was a subclass of `GrandparentClass` you couldn't do something like this:

```
parent::parent::method_2(); // trying to call grandparent::method_2
                            // but this call will fail
```

But you can directly refer to ancestor classes by name, so this would work:

```
GrandparentClass::method_2();
```

And just to take it a little further, there is also a function called `class_parents()` which returns an array of every ancestor class your class inherits from. This could help if you wanted to go back, say, two ancestors, but you didn't know its specific name for some reason, you could still call the function using `eval()`.

For example, this code would call `GrandparentClass::method_2()` without directly referencing the class by name in your code:

```
$parents = class_parents($this);
eval(end($parents) . "::method_2();");
```

Hope that helps.